Store python return value in Jenkins file
I have a Jenkins pipeline, one of its steps is to execute a python script(this python script simply returns a "hello world" string) and I want to store its returned value, not printed value in a variable, my pipeline stage looks like this:
        stage("Execute"){
            steps {
                    script {
                            sh 'python3 -V'
                            def command = "python3 test.py "
                            def process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)
                            def output = process.in.text
                            process.waitFor()
                            println output
                    }
            }
        }

Above code is able to print out python3 version successfully, but it will return an python not found error when it runs Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3": error=2, No such file or directory

Am I missing any python path configuration in my pipeline?

you can do which python3 in your sh command. Also echo $PATH to see if python3 is in a known location

Hi, when I do which python3 it returns /bin/python3, and echo $PATH give me this /opt/node/bin:/opt/maven/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/sa_109426724188329927672/.local/bin:/home/sa_109426724188329927672/bin

You already know how to use the sh step, why bother with all the Runtime stuff? Just do:
stage("Execute"){
    steps {
        script {
            def output = sh script: 'python3 test.py', returnStdout: true
            echo output
        }
    }
}

